# Are there "Pop Up Blockers"/Add Ons that change a post to a get in IE8?

Tags: html, popup

We have some code where the user clicks a link which launches a pop up window.  The code that creates the window then does an HTTP post to the window.  Once the post has succeeded, the page is redirected (as a javascript location) to a PDF that was created during the post.

One person is getting an error where the posted data is not getting posted.  In fact, the request is coming across as a GET.

Originally I thought this may be some kind of bookmark to the original page issue.  But it happens in two different places that use the same concept in a different manner.  And, since the post is triggered through JavaScript and the result is immediately relocated it would be no trivial matter to actually get a link to the original page.

So, the question is, are there any "pop-up" blocker like security tools that would allow pop-up's but convert all POSTS on them to GETS?

Example Call:

```
function LoadPDF(File){
    document.forms[0].PDF.value = File;
    win = "Window" + Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
    open("",win,'toolbar=no');

    function SubmitForm(){
        document.forms[0].action = 'CreatePDF.cfm';
        document.forms[0].target = win;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }

        //Give window time to open.
        setTimeout(SubmitForm,550);
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code on how the popup is generated and the POST request?

Comment: Get your user to disable all extensions and/or plugins.  Check that the problem goes away.  After that have them enable these one at a time until the problem shows up again.  Then have them remove all but that last one and see if the problem remains.  If it does, that's the problem.  If it goes away as other plugins vanish you've got a bad synergy situation and will have to work more with mixes of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

> The code that creates the window then does an HTTP post to the window.

Popup blockers block popups as they are opening, which is pretty much the point of their existence.  It would have to be a pretty lame popup blocker that allowed the popup to open and then translated the POST to a GET.  It's possible a GreaseMonkey script or extension could translate it maybe.

Tell the user to disable any plugins/extensions and try again.